# simple input field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying simple textarea validation with `regex pattern`(it should allow only numbers.characters,comma,space and dot).But its not working.
If I click `click button` without values,Directly its showing `alert()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sub").click(function(){
    debugger
    var a=$('.showReason' ).val();
    alert(a)
    var regex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/;
    if(!regex.test(a)==false){
   $('.showReason' ).addClass('box');
    } else {
      alert("gud");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box{
border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" class="showReason col-xs-12 form-control required" ></textarea>
 <button id="sub">
 click
 </button>
```

Comment: I don't really get the problem, could you explain what should happen when clicking the button without any text in the textarea?

Comment: `!regex.test(a)==false`? I think the double negative is confusing you

Comment: You seem to have a double negative `!regex.test(a)==false`?

Comment: I just entered `welcom.` but its showing error.In text field It should allow to enter character,number,space,comma and dot.

Comment: why not use ? `<input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9,.!? ]*$" title="only numbers.characters,comma,space and dot">`

Comment: Maybe use a non-whitespace character regexp: [^\s]